# How to condition the choice of the SCM checkout in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How to condition the choice of the source manager (git or svn) in Jenkins based on a parameter ?

I tried the Conditional BuildStep Plugin but it's only for build steps or after build steps, and i know i can do this with shell scripts but if it's possible i prefer use the SCM checkout.

I'm using Jenkins ver. 1.594

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did two job and I choose in the flow